# Run FMLECmd.exe without compatibility mode

Tags: java, windows, fmle

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1

Adobe FMLE 3.2

I was always executing FMLECmd.exe from Java-code without any problems. But suddenly smth happened and the stream couldn't start anymore.
Setting the compatibility mode to Windows XP SP3 solved the problem of execution.

**But the new one appeared:** launching the stream in compatibility mode should be performed as Administrator. I switched off the UAC popup and solved the problem of programmatical stream-starting.

**But then the new problem appeared:** when I want to kill the FMLECmd.exe process programmatically (to stop the stream) I get the message that 'Access is denied'. I guess the reason is that I started stream as Administrator, but process-killing is held as a usual user.

**So, the question:** Are there any ways to make FMLE work without compatibility mode? Or are there any ways to kill that process without being administrator from Java?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find how to run it without compatibility mode but could kill the process:

1. Create a batch file which contains
   `taskkill /F /IM FMLECmd.exe`
2. Create a shortcut of this batch file
3. Go to the properties of shortcut.
4. Choose **Shortcut** tab
5. Click **Advanced** btn
6. Tick **Run as administrator** option
7. Start the shortcut using this java code:

   `String command = "start "+ pathToShortcut;
    String[] cmd = { "cmd.exe", "/c", command };
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    pb.start();`

That worked for me